# Azure ADB2C "sub" missing from claims collection

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am hooking up an AD tenant as a federated identity provider to an ADB2C tenant. At the final orchestration step, where the claims are sent:

`<OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />`

I am getting the error: "B2C_1A_signup_signin' policy in '{ourTenant}.onmicrosoft.com' specifies the subject claim 'sub' which is missing in the claims collection., Exception Type:PolicyException"

However, when I inspect this in VSCode or directly in Application Insights, it appears that the claim is indeed present in the collection:

From Application Insights...

**Exceptions**

'B2C_1A_signup_signin' policy in '{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com' specifies the subject claim 'sub' which is missing in the claims collection.

**Claims**

accountType: staff

alternativeSecurityId:
{"type":6,"identityProvider":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{id}/v2.0","key":"Z3J...."}

authenticationSource: socialIdpAuthentication

displayName: Paul

identityProvider: [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{id}/v2.0](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Bid%7D/v2.0)

issuerUserId: grGppTQoYIYEseflV6OklohGWHJCiHVuo0WnqTm3bY8

**sub: grGppTQoYIYEseflV6OklohGWHJCiHVuo0WnqTm3bY8**

tenantId: {id}

upnUserName: bd3e055d-172e-4282-b6a3-47cac965d10a

userPrincipalName: cpim_bd3e055d-172e-4282-b6a3-47cac965d10a@{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com

Full code below. Only steps 1,2 and 6 will execute (3,4,5) are for the local sign in):

```
<UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignIn">
      <OrchestrationSteps>

         <!-- Check if staff or member -->

        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
   
            <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="AccountTypeInputCollectorClaimsExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AccountTypeInputCollector"/>
            </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- HANDLE STAFF LOGIN-->
         
         <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
        <Value>accountType</Value>
        <Value>staff</Value>
        <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
      </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange-Staff" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
             <ClaimsExchange Id="FederatedClaimsExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-Company-OpenIdConnect" />

          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- HANDLE NON-STAFF LOGINS-->

        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
        <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
        <Value>accountType</Value>
        <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
      </Precondition>
      <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
        <Value>accountType</Value>
        <Value>staff</Value>
        <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
      </Precondition>
    </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
            <Value>accountType</Value>
            <Value>staff</Value>
            <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
           </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
         
        <!-- This step reads any user attributes that we may not have received when in the token. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
        <Preconditions>
         <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
            <Value>accountType</Value>
            <Value>staff</Value>
            <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
      </OrchestrationSteps>
      <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
    </UserJourney>
```

The Technical Profile:

```
<ClaimsProvider>
  <Domain>Company</Domain>
  <DisplayName>Login using Staff_Test_AD</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-Company-OpenIdConnect">
      <DisplayName>Continue with Active Directory</DisplayName>
      <Description>Login with an account in the staff Active Directory</Description>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect"/>
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="METADATA">https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
        <Item Key="client_id">{Settings:ADFederatedTestApplicationId}</Item>
        <Item Key="response_types">code</Item>
        <Item Key="scope">openid profile</Item>
        <Item Key="response_mode">form_post</Item>
        <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
        <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
        <Item Key="DiscoverMetadataByTokenIssuer">true</Item>
        <!-- The key below allows you to specify each of the Azure AD tenants that can be used to sign in. Update the GUIDs below for each tenant. -->
        <Item Key="ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes">https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Settings:ADFederatedTenantId}</Item>
        <!-- The commented key below specifies that users from any tenant can sign-in. Uncomment if you would like anyone with an Azure AD account to be able to sign in. -->
        <!-- <Item Key="ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes">https://login.microsoftonline.com/</Item> -->
     
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_StaffAdTest"/>
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="sub"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="sub" PartnerClaimType="sub"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" PartnerClaimType="tid"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
        <!-- <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="localAccountAuthentication" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" /> -->
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" PartnerClaimType="iss" />

        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName"/>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName"/>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId"/>
        <!-- <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId"/> -->
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
      <!-- <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD"/> -->
        <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin"/>

    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

Have ensured the claim is passed through in the claims set
Added Application Insights and verified

---EDITED---

Including the Relying Party as solved in case it helps anyone else

```
<TrustFrameworkPolicy 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06" 
PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0" 
TenantId="{Settings:Tenant}" 
PolicyId="B2C_1A_signup_signin" 
PublicPolicyUri="http://{Settings:Tenant}/B2C_1A_signup_signin" 
TenantObjectId="{Settings:TenantObjectId}"
DeploymentMode="Development" 
UserJourneyRecorderEndpoint="urn:journeyrecorder:applicationinsights">
  <BasePolicy>
    <TenantId>{Settings:Tenant}</TenantId>
    <PolicyId>B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions_SeamlessMigration</PolicyId>
  </BasePolicy>
  <RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn" />
    <Endpoints>
      <!--points to refresh token journey when app makes refresh token request-->
      <Endpoint Id="Token" UserJourneyReferenceId="RedeemRefreshToken" />
    </Endpoints>
    <UserJourneyBehaviors>
      <JourneyInsights TelemetryEngine="ApplicationInsights" InstrumentationKey="{Settings:ApplicationInsightsKey}" DeveloperMode="true" ClientEnabled="false" ServerEnabled="true" TelemetryVersion="1.0.0" />
    </UserJourneyBehaviors>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Settings:TenantObjectId}" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </RelyingParty>
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything that sticks out!

It may be related to commenting out "CreateSubjectClaim..."?

What does your RP look like?

Have you tried something like:

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="temp" PartnerClaimType="sub"/>
```

in the federation and then:

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="temp" PartnerClaimType="sub"/>
```

in the RP?

Comment: Thank you so much. I had been so obsessed with getting the claims passed correctly through my federated Technical Profile I missed the fact that I had missed out on ensuring the claims were correctly named and passed to the RP.


`<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub"/>`

in both Technical Profile and Relying Party.

@rbayb If I could buy you a beer I would!